# Uploading a photo to my website

Tags: c#, windows, upload, uwp, photo

I'm currently developing a photo upload app for Windows 10 store. I'm done with the UI but I have no idea how to upload the file to the server.

I'm planning to buy a hosting and a domain if in need. Which codes do I need? I've found a PHP demo where I can submit a form including a input file method but I don't think I can use it with the app.

Can you suggest something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UploadOperation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) from namespace Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer

official example is:

```
    using Windows.Foundation; 
    using Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer;
    using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
    using Windows.Storage;

    private async void StartUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(serverAddressField.Text.Trim());
            FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
            uploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", file.Name);

            UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);

            // Attach progress and completion handlers.
            HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException("Upload Error", ex);
        }
    }
```

On a server side you can use [File Upload RESTful Web Service with ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-implement-file-upload-restful.html)

Comment: Hey @Alexej-sommer thanks for the C# side. Do you know what should I have on my website to be able to write it in the serverAddressField? I mean, which HTML or PHP code do I need?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm inspecting the codes very carefully, I'll write back when I can make it work :)